# CountVectorizer in Scikit Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, vectorization

I'm not sure when creating an instance of the CountVectorizer class, what is the difference between
 `vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=word_tokenize)`  and `vectorizer = CountVectorizer`

Please help me make it clear. 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `CountVectorizer` does not tokenize the input. Tokenization is the process of demarcating and possibly classifying sections of a string of input characters. In other words, it turns a long string like `'This is the input'` into a sequence:

```
['This', 'is', 'the', 'input']
```

If you specify the `tokenizer` argument with a callable
in `CountVectorizer`, it will use this function to tokenize the input ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)).

Comment: Thank for your clarification